# How to get value of IEnumerable using two parameters

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I use the following code and it does not fail at compile time, but I do not seem to have entered correctly the input codes and parameters!

```
public IEnumerable<TimeWorkMonthly> Get(int id,int id1)
{
    using (EmployeeDbEntities Entities = new EmployeeDbEntities())
    {
        var result = Entities.TimeWorkMonthlies.Where(e => e.KartNo == id && e.TermID == id1).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

In my browser I type the address below:

```
http://localhost:49643/api/Employees/1461/9604
```

But I get a `404 error`.

While using an input `value(id)`, I get the correct output from the program.

Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: You need this URL: `http://localhost:49643/api/Employees/1461?id1=9604`

Comment: The problem is unrelated to the generic `IEnumerable` interface; it is only related to the URL encoding conventions of the used hosting framework.

Comment: Or add the `[Route("{id}/{id1}")]` above the method (or just `[Route("{id1}")]` depending on the default Route.).

Comment: Side note: You don't need that `ToList()`, the `Where` method returns an `IEnumerable` and so does your own method.

Comment: yes it is true i need this url : http://localhost:49643/api/Employees/1461?id1=9604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the route `http://localhost:49643/api/Employees/1461/9604` does not resolve the parameter `id1` correctly.

The default route looks something like this (in WebApiConfig.cs):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", // only "id" parameter is mapped from URL
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Add another route that also maps the `id1` from the URL:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API with additional Id",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{id1}", // URL with TWO parameters
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, id1 = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Further reading: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).